# Compiling the whole project without stopping at the first error with Qt Creator

Tags: qt, build, compiler-errors, qt-creator

Now the build process stops as soon as the first error is found. 
Is it possible to let it continue, compile all the files and have all the errors at once?

Platform: QtCreator 3.0, Qt 5.2, clang, MacOS X 10.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the make option in the `Projects -> Build & Run -> Build steps -> Make -> Make arguments` settings. Try this option:

```
-k, --keep-going
```

> Continue as much as possible after an error.  While the target that failed, and those that depend on it, cannot be remade, the other dependencies of these targets  can  be  processed all the same.

Answer (score 1):

do not literally enter "-k, --keep-going" into the "make arguments" text field. instead enter just one or the other, no comma.  this may be obvious to those who know it, but it is not obvious if you don't already know.